# Call app with sudo and custom environment variable

Tags: linux, sudo, environment-variables

I need to call `sqlplus` with oracle user sudo to clearly specified DB (env var `ORACLE_SID`) by one line command. The usual way to do it consists of 2 steps:

```
$ sudo -u oracle -i
$ ORACLE_SID=DBNAME sqlplus / as sysdba
```

But I need to do it in one line (to save time, reasonably). I try to do it simply like this:

```
$ sudo -u oracle -i ORACLE_SID=DBNAME sqlplus / as sysdba
```

But it seems that `sqlplus` does not see changing of `ORACLE_SID` env var and connects to default DB. Also I can not exclude `-i` sudo option because I need to be sure that all other environment variables initialized perfectly.

How can I run application with sudo and custom environment variable in my case?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The best way to solve question is to use the following command:

```
sudo -u oracle -i sh -c "ORACLE_SID=DBNAME sqlplus / as sysdba"
```

And if we want to pass sql script straightly at one line:

```
sudo -u oracle -i sh -c "ORACLE_SID=DBNAME sqlplus / as sysdba" <<-EOF
  SELECT 1 FROM DUAL;
EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following command:

```
sudo -i su - oracle -c 'ORACLE_SID=DBNAME && sqlplus'
```

**Explanation:**

```
"sudo -i" will take care of the environment variables.
"su - user" will consider the user's environment variables
"-c" -> the command you wish to issue.
```

Comment: It works, thanks. How su works here? If I directly call `su - oracle -c '...'` su asks me for a password. But if I use it with sudo as you wrote there is not a password prompt.

Comment: "su" requires you to insert the password of the user you're trying to run the command as. "sudo" requires you to enter your own user password and as long as your user is a member of the sudoers group then you'll be able to run the command as the other user. Also I believe that you've already inserted your "sudo" password once in that terminal session which is why you weren't asked to re-enter the password, but if you run it on a fresh terminal session you will be required to supply your user's password again.

Comment: If my answer solves your issue then please feel free to mark it as the solution, thanks.

Comment: It pretty solves the described question. Thanks. But now I want to execute a script directly in one step. The problem here is that script cames from stdin and quotes for `-c` option of `su` are the problem. So I need to call sqlplus in this way: `sqlplus -S / as sysdba << EOF <some sql script here> EOF`. How can I do it in one line?

Comment: I thoroughly tested the command you suggested. The main problem with it is that user should have sudo rights for root. See my answer below where I posted the nicest way to solve my question.